# Sorting lunch items in a python list

Tags: python, list, formatting

I'm trying to format a list with the lunch in my school every day that I get from an API (one normal & vegetarian option) in Python. Some times the list will only have one item, when the school is closed. Here's a translated version of the list I get from the api:

> [['Closed'], ['Pasta Al Carne with shredded beef, tomato salsa and grated cheese', 'Pasta with ratatouille'], ['Pancake with cottage cheese and jam', 'Pancake with cottage cheese and jam'], ['Breaded fish fillet with cold sauce boiled potatoes', 'Vegetarian moussaka'], ['Hamburgers with bread and classic accessories',' Vegetarian burgers with classic accessories']]

Right now I have this code:
`"Monday: {}\nTuesday: {}\nWednesday: {}\nThursday: {}\nFriday: {}".format(*lunch)`
which outputs to this:

> Monday: ['Closed']
>
> Tuesday: ['Pasta Al Carne with shredded steak, tomato salsa and grated
> cheese', 'Pasta with ratatouille']
>
> *etc...*

How can I format each day individually, to make it look more like this?

> Monday: Closed
>
> Tuesday: Pasta Al Carne with shredded steak, tomato salsa and grated
> cheese. Vegetarian: Pasta with ratatouille
>
> Wednesday: Pancake with cottage cheese and jam. Vegetarian: Pancake with cottage cheese and jam
>
> *etc...*

I have been searching for a while how to format lists in Python, but since I'm new it's pretty hard to know what to search for.
Thanks!

Comment: You're actually getting a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `join` is what you need here:

```
data = [['Closed'], ['Pasta Al Carne with shredded beef, tomato salsa and grated cheese', 'Pasta with ratatouille'], ['Pancake with cottage cheese and jam', 'Pancake with cottage cheese and jam'], ['Breaded fish fillet with cold sauce boiled potatoes', 'Vegetarian moussaka'], ['Hamburgers with bread and classic accessories',' Vegetarian burgers with classic accessories']]

lunch = [', '.join(item) for item in data]
print("Monday: {}\nTuesday: {}\nWednesday: {}\nThursday: {}\nFriday: {}".format(*lunch))
```

the trick here is the `str.join` function, which lets you use a string, in our case ", " as a separator for list items

Answer (score 0):

> **zip(*iterables)**
>
> zip(iterator1, iterqator2, iterator3 ...)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th
>   element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator
>   stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

lunch = [['Closed'], ['Pasta Al Carne with shredded beef, tomato salsa and grated cheese', 'Pasta with ratatouille'], ['Pancake with cottage cheese and jam', 'Pancake with cottage cheese and jam'], ['Breaded fish fillet with cold sauce boiled potatoes', 'Vegetarian moussaka'], ['Hamburgers with bread and classic accessories',' Vegetarian burgers with classic accessories']]
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

```
r =list(zip(days, lunch)) # ('Monday', ['Closed']), ('Tuesday', ['Pasta Al Carne with shredded beef, tomato salsa and grated cheese', 'Pasta with ratatouille']), ...
for item in r:
    if 'Closed' not in item[1]: # Check if closed
        print ("{}: {}. Vegeterian: {}".format(item[0], item[1][0], item[1][1]))
    else:
        print ("{}: {}".format(item[0], item[1][0]))
```

output:

```
Monday: Closed
Tuesday: Pasta Al Carne with shredded beef, tomato salsa and grated cheese. Vegeterian: Pasta with ratatouille
Wednesday: Pancake with cottage cheese and jam. Vegeterian: Pancake with cottage cheese and jam
Thursday: Breaded fish fillet with cold sauce boiled potatoes. Vegeterian: Vegetarian moussaka
Friday: Hamburgers with bread and classic accessories. Vegeterian:  Vegetarian burgers with classic accessories
```